# Different definitions of topological group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Recently I discovered the definition of topological group. So, topological group is an abstract group $G$ endowed with topological structure such that the maps $mult: G\times G\longrightarrow G$ and $inv:G\longrightarrow G$ (multiplication and inversion) are continuous. I'd like to understand if it is enough just to suppose $mult$ to be continuous. Could you give me some slight hint?

Comment: It is not enough for us to assume just multiplication is continuous. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/can-continuity-of-inverse-be-omitted-from-the-definition-of-topological-group)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not enough to assume that the multiplication map is continuous. See questions  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/can-continuity-of-inverse-be-omitted-from-the-definition-of-topological-group) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151878/why-metrizable-group-requires-continuity-of-inverse).

However, if the topology on $G$ is nice enough, then it is enough to assume that just the multiplication map is continuous.

> **Theorem** (Ellis, 1957): Let $G$ be a group with a locally compact Hausdorff topology such that the multiplication map $G \times G \rightarrow G$ is separately continuous. Then $G$ is a topological group.